# Не работает focus() с transition

Tags: javascript, css

Допустим у меня есть такой код.
Почему focus не работает когда есть transition: all ... ; ?

Еще я заметил что это конкретно с visibility такое, если в transition указать всё кроме visibility, то работать будет, но всё же почему так

```js
let input = document.querySelector('#input');
let focus = document.querySelector('#focus');
let blur  = document.querySelector('#blur');

focus.addEventListener('click', function() {
    input.classList.add('_active');
    input.focus();
});

blur.addEventListener('click', function() {
    input.classList.remove('_active');
    input.blur();
});
```

```css
#input {
    visibility: hidden;
    transition: .5s ease-in;
}

#input._active {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<form>
    <input value="text" id="input">
    <input type="button" value="focus" id="focus">
    <input type="button" value="blur"  id="blur">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`visibility` - указывает видимость элемента, в данном случае вы используете `hidden`, а он судя [по документации](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/visibility#hidden), не даёт элементу получить фокус, на элемент хоть и можно нажимать, но фокуса он больше не получит. Если вы хотите сделать плавное исчезание и сохранить фокус, то тогда указывайте `opacity` и в пропорцию `transition` добавьте `opacity` чтобы плавность только применялась на эту пропорцию и не вызывала лишних нагрузок.

```js
let input = document.querySelector('#input');
let focus = document.querySelector('#focus');
let blur  = document.querySelector('#blur');

focus.addEventListener('click', function() {
    input.classList.add('_active');
    input.focus();
});

blur.addEventListener('click', function() {
    input.classList.remove('_active');
    input.blur();
});
```

```css
#input {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .5s ease-in opacity;
}

#input._active {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<form>
    <input value="text" id="input">
    <input type="button" value="focus" id="focus">
    <input type="button" value="blur"  id="blur">
</form>
```